# GWT : two DOM events on same div, priority and how to deactivate the second event when the first is called?

Tags: javascript, events, gwt, event-bubbling, event-propagation

I've got a Widget which have two Dom mouseDown handlers :

First, I code with GWT but I think the problem is probably Javascript related.

One of this handler registration is defined in a class named Resizable which allows my widget to be resizable.
The second handler registration is defined in a class named Draggable which allows my widget to be draggable.

So, in each constructor of these two classes (giving the widget in argument), I've got :

```
widget.addDomHandler(this, MouseDownEvent.getType());
```

I want to prioritize my dom event to force the Resizable handler to be called first and only after the Draggable handler. How can I achieve it ?

Moreover, I want to stop the event if the resizable handler is called.
I tried the `event.stopPropagation()` function but it seems that the event can only be stopped for parents and not for a similar event on the same widget.

How can I stop this event to avoid the draggable handler to be called if my widget is resizable ?

I precise that these two classes are completely independant as my widget can be Resizable but not Draggable, draggable and not resizable or both. So if I can, I want to avoid code intersection between these two classes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `event.cancel()` instead of `event.stopPropagation()`? That might help!